# Admin Post List table Query filtering "WHERE" for custom post type

Tags: query, pre-get-posts, wp-list-table

So I have been searching for a solution on how I can dynamically change a CPT post list table query by filter the result WHERE Status is equaled to some custom status.

I have searched using function `pre_get_posts`, but that seems to use `ORDERRBY` and not `WHERE`.

I have also searched for other functions such as `post_clauses`.

Basically, I want to change the results on page load based on the current user's role and only show post that has a certain status. Is this possible?

```
/*Change results based on the current user's role and status */ 
           
function posts_for_current_role($query) {
    global $pagenow;
 
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;
 
    if( current_user_can('editor')):
      //Add query where clause to status equals "working".
    endif;

    if( current_user_can('administrator')):
      //Add $query WHERE clause to status equals "completed".
    endif;


    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_role');
```

Comment: Have you tried setting [the `post_status` parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome. This works! Thanks @Milo

```
/*Change results based on the current user's role and status */ 

function posts_for_current_role($query) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;

    if( current_user_can('editor')):
      //Add query where clause to status equals "working".
      $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'working', 'draft' ) );
    endif;

    if( current_user_can('administrator')):
      $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'published') );
    endif;


    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_role');
```